# How does one load files from a folder into a tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to use a kaggle dataset for sign language recognition, the data is in sequences and each sequence stored in a file. There are around 94 thousand of them in total, they are floats normalized from 0 to 1 with nulls replaced with -1's. They are not images at all just vectors of locations in space.

I have them preprocessed into pandas dataframes with 32 frames as rows and 222 colums all saved in one folder as parquet files.
How does one read them into a tensorflow dataset and then label them?
do i need to reshape them first and append them all together into one flat 7000 column tensor with rows being each sign?
I'm very lost at the moment and any help would be appreciated

So far I have tried to read the files

import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk(output_path):
for filename in filenames:

```
  temp_sign = pd.read_parquet(filename)
  signs.append(temp_sign, axis= 2)
```

tf.data.dataset.from_tensor_slices(signs, name=None)